# Difference between deadlock and race condition?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, thread-safety, deadlock

Im sure this question has been answered before, but i was just wondering if they are related in anyway. specifically will a race condition within a piece of code lead to a deadlock.

Comment: @GergoErdosi I have made it more specific underneath the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, a race condition will not necessarily end in a deadlock. This will only occur if, in the process of dealing with a race condition, two processes are both waiting on one another to finish. Please review the definitions of [Deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) and [Race Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Specifically the section on critical and non-critical race conditions may be of particular interest.